How can I make a nested Serializer available inside the create() of a ModelSerializer without making the nested Serializer read_only=False
I'm in a bit of a dilemma. The task is to take in a json that has some Info about a Bunny Litter and the Birthed Bunnies. I got a ThrowInfoSerializer with the Throw Model (Throw = Litter, non-english speaking country). Inside the create of the ThrowInfoSerializer I want to save a new Litter and the corresponding new Bunnies so I call new_bunnies = validated_data.pop('new_bunnies') and want to extract the new Bunny data from the validated_data.
The problem is: since the new Bunny data is stored inside another ModelSerializer that is linked to the Bunny Model, and is BunnySerializer(many=True, read_only=True) read_only it isn't available in the validated_data inside the create().
But if I want to make new_bunnies read_only=False to make the info part of the validated_data inside create() i get this error:
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `new_bunnies` on serializer `ThrowInfoSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Throw` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Throw' object has no attribute 'new_bunnies'.


Which makes sense since the the ThrowInfoSerializer is tied to the Throw Model.
I can't really make another serializer and put ThrowInfoSerializer and the BunnySerializers on the same level since I still need the Throw Info of the ThrowInfoSerializer for saving new Bunnies.
Throw = Litter, we messed up the translation
Here is the code:
Serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer, ModelSerializer, SerializerMethodField

from bunny_service.bunny_utils import getStudBookKeeperOfUser
from bunny_service.models import Throw, Bunny

class BunnySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    sex = serializers.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Bunny
        fields = ['sex', 'RID', 'COLID']

class ParentBunnySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bunny
        fields = ['RID', 'COLID', 'l_ear', 'r_ear', 'UID_owner']

    def validate(self, attrs):
         # Check if a Bunny with the given attributes exists
        if not Bunny.objects.filter(
                RID=attrs.get('RID'),
                COLID=attrs.get('COLID'),
                l_ear=attrs.get('l_ear'),
                r_ear=attrs.get('r_ear'),
                UID_owner=attrs.get('UID_owner')
        ).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("A bunny with those properties does not exist")
        return attrs


class ThrowInfoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    count = SerializerMethodField()
    remaining = SerializerMethodField()
    new_bunnies = BunnySerializer(many=True)


    BID_buck = ParentBunnySerializer()
    BID_doe = ParentBunnySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Throw
        fields = ['thrown_on', 'covered_on', 'death_count', 'BID_buck', 'BID_doe', 'count', 'remaining', 'new_bunnies']

    def get_count(self, instance):
        return instance.bunny_set.count()

    def get_remaining(self, instance):
        return self.get_count(instance) - instance.death_count

    def create(self, validated_data, **kwargs):
        print(validated_data)
        new_bunnies = validated_data.pop('new_bunnies')

        BID_buck = Bunny.objects.get(**validated_data.pop('BID_buck', None))
        BID_doe = Bunny.objects.get(**validated_data.pop('BID_doe', None))

        validated_data['BID_buck'] = BID_buck
        validated_data['BID_doe'] = BID_doe
        validated_data['UID_stud_book_keeper'] = getStudBookKeeperOfUser(self.context['user'])

        throw = Throw.objects.create(**validated_data)

        print(new_bunnies)
        for bunny in new_bunnies:
            Bunny.objects.create(
                **bunny,
                TID=throw,
                UID_owner=self.context['user'],
                CID=self.context['user'].CID_breeding_club,
                l_ear="TO BE IMPLEMENTED", #TODO: implement
                r_ear="TO BE IMPLEMENTED"
            )

        print(Bunny.objects.all())
        return throw

models.py
class Bunny(models.Model):
    l_ear = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    r_ear = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')])
    tattooed_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    CID = models.ForeignKey(
        Club,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False
    )
    UID_owner = models.ForeignKey(
        "auth_service.User",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False,
        related_name='bunny_owners'
    )
    TID = models.ForeignKey(
        "bunny_service.Throw",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    RID = models.ForeignKey(
        "bunny_service.Race",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False
    )
    COLID = models.ForeignKey(
        "bunny_service.Color",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False
    )
    UID_tattoo_master = models.ForeignKey(
        "auth_service.User",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False,
        related_name='bunny_tattoo_master',
        null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.l_ear + " / " + self.r_ear


class Throw(models.Model):
    covered_on = models.DateTimeField()
    thrown_on = models.DateTimeField()
    death_count = models.IntegerField()
    reported_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    BID_buck = models.ForeignKey(  # buck = Rammler
        Bunny,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='bunny_buck'
    )

    BID_doe = models.ForeignKey(  # doe = Häsin
        Bunny,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='bunny_doe'
    )
    UID_stud_book_keeper = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.BID_buck.UID_owner) + " / "+ str(self.thrown_on)


class Color(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Race(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    abbreviation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    SID = models.ForeignKey(
        "Section",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        blank=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Custom KEZ User supporting email authentication instead of username
    """
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    username = None

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    CID_breeding_club = models.ForeignKey(
        to='club_service.Club',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    # Address
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    zip_code = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)  # TODO: validate length
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)

    telephone = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['last_name']


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


I hope this makes sense

The error you get Original exception text was: 'Throw' object has no attribute 'new_bunnies'. is because there really isn't a field named new_bunnies. So to fix this you can:

Change new_bunnies with the name of the field that actually exist on the model.

Define specify to what field is new_bunny making reference to:


new_bunnies = UUIDField(source='the.referenced.field.in.the.model)

In case of needing to navigate relations in the source field, separate them with dots .. And of course, change UUIDField with the field type that of the data you are going to receive.

Or if new_bunnies is not a specific model field, you can simply define it like in the second option, but without the source field.

new_bunnies = UUIDField()

This way you are defining a field for the serializer although it doesn't exist in the model. But in this approach you will need a custom create() function to handle what happens with that new field as it is not part of the model and django won't know what to do with it.
I hope this helps you.
